# Redirect javascript failing in all but Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, redirect, safari

Trying to have a webpage manage a redirect, if a deeplink fails to open.  If the deeplink opens, great. if it doesn't within 2 seconds, I want it to go to my website.

```
     <script type="javascript">
     setTimeout(function () { window.location = "http://mywebsite.com"; }, 25);
     window.location = "my://app";    
     </script>
```

I've tested in Chrome and it works, but Firefox, IE, and Safari all block the script.

Anyone have any idea on how to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href`? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, tried that.  Same errors happen. IE: blocks script and Firefox provides an error that says:"The address wasn't understood."  Chrome handles it fine.

Comment: is the actual address you're trying to go to have "my://" at the start?

Answer (score 0):

window.location.assign("http:mywebsite.com") may be a better alternative as I believe calling that function fires some additional events that may make the lifecycle of the page easy to manage.

Also in about all except Chrome you can use an IFrame to attempt to launch your protocol handler. This will help prevent the page going to about:blank and/or your script stopping due to navigating away from the page.

```
var createIframe = function(id, url, timeout, callback) {
    var iframe;
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.hidden = true;
    iframe.id = id;
    iframe.src = url;

    var data = {}
    data.id = id;
    data.iframe = iframe;
    return setTimeout(callback, timeout, null, data);
}

createIframe('tempFrame', 'http://mywebsite.com', 25, function(err, data) {
  if(!err && data){
      var iframe = data.iframe;
      var id = data.id;
      iframe = document.getElementById(id);
      iframe.parent.removeChild(iframe);
  }
  else {
     console.log('There was an error createing and removeing the iframe');
  }
}
```